# Encoding errors with ActiveModelSerializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I have a Rails app using ActiveModelSerializers version 0.8.3 to create a JSON API. I am getting encoding errors whenever non-standard characters are present in my database. For example if I have a message object with `message.body = "ça va"` and I send this in my controller using:

```
def show
  render json: Message.find(params[:id])
end
```

I get the following error:

```
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError in MessagesController#show
"\xC3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
```

I think this error comes from the to_json method implemented in ActiveModelSerializers. Is there a way to fix this?

Many thanks